# MongoDB - Filter array with array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have one data example like this one in MongoDB.

```
{
  id: 628a8683fc489c315b330ade,
  examName : 'Final Exam',
  schedule: 
  {
    scheduleDate : '2021-10-18T17:00:00.000+00:00'
    scheduleName : 'Package Test'
    package:[
       {
         exclude_question:[1,2],
         namePackage:testing
         packageId:628a89c2fc489c315b330b01      
       }

    ]
  },
  question:[
    {
       id:1,
       question:'hello can u test it?'
       answer:'No'
    }
    {
       id:3,
       question:'Is it working?'
       answer:'No'
    }
    {
       id:2,
       question:'Should i repeat?'
       answer:'Yes'
    }
  ]
}
```

**Condition:**
Basically at `schedule.package` it is possible to have more than one value, but I have already filtered it so only one value is in the array.

Now I need to filter the question with `exclude_question`. Value of `exclude_question` is an array `id` of the question and now I need to only show the question that is not in `exlcude_question`.

So the output that I expect is like this one:

```
{
  id: 628a8683fc489c315b330ade,
  examName : 'Final Exam',
  schedule: {.......},
  question:[
    {
       id:3,
       question:'Is it working?'
       answer:'No'
    }
  ]
}
```

It only shows the question with id: 3 because it is not in `exclude_question`. I'm kinda confused about how to get the value from the array inside the array to filter the question array. If you have any suggestions I will very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way to do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "question": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$question",
          "as": "q",
          "cond": {
            "$not": [
              {"$in": ["$$q.id", {"$first": "$schedule.package.exclude_question"}]}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i13BS5rnJg_).

Answer (score 2):

1. `$set` - Create `exclude_questions` field:

   1.1. `$reduce` - Iterate every document of `schedule.package`, merge (`$concatArrays`) `exclude_question` array value into an new array and return it.
2. `$set` - Set the value for `question` field.

   2.1. `$filter` - Filter the document in `question` array field with the document's `id` `$not` `$in` `exclude_questions` array.
3. `$unset` - Remove `exclude_questions` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      exclude_questions: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$schedule.package",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.exclude_question"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      question: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$question",
          cond: {
            $not: {
              $in: [
                "$$this.id",
                "$exclude_questions"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "exclude_questions"
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HMMZXJH2HrJ)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aggregation like following,

- you already mentioned `shedule.package` has always one element, so the arrays what you need to exclude. For safety operator we use `$ifNull`
- `$filter` to exclude the questions that you need to exclude
- `$unset` to remove the varaible that we set in the first step

here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "exe_qus": {
        "$ifNull": [
          { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$schedule.package", 0 ] },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "question": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$question",
          "cond": {
            $not: {
              $in: [ "$$this.id", "$exe_qus.exclude_question" ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "exe_qus"
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KZ3V-zeQafC)**